# Configure 27" 2560x1440 for a monitor with corrupt EDID

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, resolution, displayport

I am trying to get a monitor work with my Ubuntu laptop. The monitor is this [cheap 27" Korean monitors](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/150864434755?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649&clk_rvr_id=406409241250) which has a 2560x1440 resolution -- and nothing else. Here are some specifications of this monitor:

- 2560x1440 @60Hz
- *Only* one dual link DVI-D input -- no other input port (no HDMI or display port)
- no OSD
- no scalar
- reports corrupt EDID
- does 2560x1440 @60Hz, did I say that already?

Anyways, the monitor works beautifully with my Ubuntu desktop which has an nVidia card with DVI output. However, I am having problem using this monitor with my laptop. After some searching around I found a [few](http://learnitwithme.com/?p=342) [posts](http://www.overclock.net/t/1215866/reviewed-400-2560x1440-ips-no-ag-90hz-achieva-shimian-qh270-and-catleap-q270/4510) suggesting to use an active adaptor for mini display port, so I went and bought [a mini display to dual link DVI-D adaptor.](http://www.futureshop.ca/en-CA/product/startech-startech-usb-powered-mini-displayport-to-dvi-dual-link-active-adapter-mdp2dvid-mdp2dvid/10196228.aspx?path=7a23ea6d1be00fc3a8be22b6c4eec6e1en02). When using this adaptor the monitor is recognized by `nvidia-settings` tool but with incorrect resolution information.

[image]

As you can see the monitor is incorrectly recognized and there are no other resolution available to set. This [post on ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2038997) and this other [post on overclock](http://www.overclock.net/a/sound-quieter-in-linux-than-windows-2560x1440-27-korean-display-not-working-the-problems-i-encountered-and-their-solution) both suggest that the monitor is reporting corrupt EDID file. I have tried following their instructions, but so far I have not been able to display any image on the monitor from my laptop.

The laptop I am using is an ASUS G75VW with a 1920x1080 screen. It has a VGA, an HDMI 1.4a, and a mini display port. The graphic card is an nvidia gforce gtx 660M with 2GB dedicated memory. I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on here which I upgrade from 12.04 a few weeks ago.

As I said I have tried several suggestions, including specifying `Modeline` in `xorg.conf` and also linking to EDID files I found from those forum posts above. However, I am not sure if the EDID files I found are suitable for my monitor. I think the solution to my problem consist of obtaining the EDID file of my monitor and then fixing it and modifying `xorg.conf` to force nvidia driver to load the correct resolution. However, I am not sure what steps I need to take to do this.

Here is the part of `sudo xrandr --prop` output that is related to this monitor:

```
DP-1 connected 800x600+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
    SignalFormat:   DisplayPort
    supported: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorType:  DisplayPort
    ConnectorNumber: 3 (0x00000003)
    _ConnectorLocation: 3 (0x00000003)
    800x600        60.3*+
```

I was expecting to see the EDID file in this output as was [mentioned in this post](http://learnitwithme.com/?p=342), but it is not there. I also tried adding the a new mode using `xandr` following [this document.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Dynamically_testing_different_resolutions). Here is what I did and the error I got:

```
$ cvt 2560 1440 60
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode DP-1 "2560x1440_60.00"
```

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  40

I have no idea what this error is about. I tried adding another mode, this time using the `gtf` utility instead. That did not make any difference. Here is the output of `xrandr -q`:

```
xrandr -q

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2720 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   40.0  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 800x600+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.3*+
  2560x1440_60.00 (0x3f9)  312.2MHz
    h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock   89.5KHz
    v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock   60.0Hz
  2560x1440 (0x3fa)  311.8MHz
    h: width  2560 start 2744 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock   89.4KHz
    v: height 1440 start 1441 end 1444 total 1490           clock   60.0Hz
```

And here is the closest thing I have to a working xorg.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"


 InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DFP-3"
    HorizSync       89.40
    VertRefresh     60.00
    #HorizSync       43.95
    #VertRefresh     30.00
    ModeLine       "2560x1440_60" 311.83 2560 2744 3024 3488 1440 1441 1444 1490 -hsync +vsync
    #ModeLine       "2560x1440_30" 146.27 2560 2680 2944 3328 1440 1441 1444 1465 -hsync +vsync
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Chi Mei Optoelectronics corp."
    HorizSync       44.4 - 67.1
    VertRefresh     40.0 - 60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 660M"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 660M"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    #Option    "NoLogo" "False"
    #Option        "UseEDID" "False"
    #Option        "UseEDIDDPI" "False"
    #Option    "UseEDIDFreqs" "False"
    Option         "metamodes"      "2560x1440_60"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "True"
    #Option         "metamodes" "DFP-3: 2560x1440_60 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_40 +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1024 +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x720 +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x768 +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x600 +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x480 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    #Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_40 +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

#Section "Extensions"
#    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
#EndSection
```

After several hours of tweaking X configurations, I decided it was time to ask for help here. I would really appreciate if someone with experience regarding EDID and X configuration could give me a hand to solve this issue.

Comment: I noticed on the eBay page you mentioned that it explicitly says that it doesnt' work with laptops or internal video cards.

Comment: yes I know that. As I said, I was hoping there would be a way around it, but I have not found any solution.

Comment: Aras did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm suffering with it to.

Comment: @bill no I did not. After trying so many different methods and a hand full of active and passive adaptors, I gave up. Now I have the monitor attached to my desktop computer. It's a really nice screen.

Comment: I also tried to [connect my Crossover High Res. Monitor to Intel HD Graphics 4400](http://askubuntu.com/questions/419393). Did you try PowerStrip on Windows to get the correct Linux Modeline Parameter for your monitor?

Comment: Here is an [explanation how to get the parameter with PowerStrip](http://www.x.org/wiki/FAQVideoModes/#index4h2)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem recently. I could've made a custom Xorg.conf file but that would've undermined all the nice new automatic configuration when I connected to other monitors.
**I re-wrote the corrupted EDID instead:**
Here are some reading materials:
ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data#External_links
edid-rw: https://github.com/bulletmark/edid-rw  ( this might work for you... I tried it and could read the edid but couldn't write?!  Try it first?)

You need to find the monitor's i2c address:

> i2cdetect -l
>    *// look for vga, in this case I got "1"*
>   i2cdetect 1
>    *// look for address.. in this case only one.. I got 0x50*
>   sudo i2cdump  **1 0x50** b
>   *// get the current edid*

I found a listing on the internet for my monitor's edid as part of an xorg listing in a bug post. Put it in file new.bin:

Checksum!.. This next line should spit out 0

> x=$( sum -s  new.bin | cut -d " " -f 1 ); echo "$x % 256 " |bc

Since edid-rw above didn't work for me I looked into:

**I used this to write the edid: 

WARNING - DANGEROUS - Make sure your i2c addresses are correct and insert them below!**

> cat new.bin | hexdump -v -e '"sudo i2cset -y **1 0x50** 0x%_ax 0x" /1 "%02X b\n"'

check final result:
 
(make sure to use the address info you found above using i2cdetect instead of " 1  0x50 ")

> sudo i2cdump  **1 0x50** b >test.bin
>   cat test.bin
>   x=$( sum -s  test.bin | cut -d " " -f 1 ); echo "$x % 256 " |bc
>   should return 0 if good

Comment: cool, thanks for sharing this! I will give it a shot when I have a change. Can you explain a bit more what exactly is happening in the last two steps? Are you modifying the edid and copying it back to the monitor itself?

Comment: Yes, it's writing the new EDID back to the monitor.  I found the correct edid for my monitor in a boot log someone else posted and google indexed.