# connect Crossover High Res. Monitor to Intel HD Graphics 4400

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, resolution, intel-graphics

I tried to attach my external *Crossover* monitor to my *Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro* with help from this [page on notebookcheck.com](http://www.notebookcheck.com/2560x1440-oder-2560x1600-ueber-HDMI-ansteuern.89837.0.html).

My monitor seems to be able to display only 2560x1440  at    60.0, `xrandr` shows this output:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1800, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 3200x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   3200x1800      60.0*+   48.0  
   2048x1536      60.0  
   ...
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440      60.0 +
```

That [page on notebookcheck.com](http://www.notebookcheck.com/2560x1440-oder-2560x1600-ueber-HDMI-ansteuern.89837.0.html) sais in german:

`xrandr` shows the possible resolutios of your monitors.

Now enter

```
cvt 2560 1440 30
```

that will generate the modeline "2560x1440_30.00" :

```
# 2560x1440 29.94 Hz (CVT) hsync: 43.95 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
146.25  2560 2680 2944 3328  1440 1443 1448 1468 -hsync +vsync
```

Create the new resolution with

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_30.00"  146.25  2560 2680 2944 3328  1440 1443 1448 1468 -hsync +vsync
```

and add it with

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "2560x1440_30.00"
```

I tried that but the monitor doesen't work correct: first it seems to work, but when you close any window on it, a **shadow** of that window stays on the screen. after moving some windows around the scereen is full of artefacts

I also tried 60Hz but that was even worse