# 15.04: I can't change the resolution of my second screen (Nvidia)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution

I have installed the last proprietary Nvidia driver installed (346.59) on a GTX 750 card.
After the upgrade to 15.04 (Kubuntu) I can't change the resolution of my second screen up to 800x600.
340 driver is the same.

[image]

What is the problem ?

**Edit:** This is the same problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211262/configure-27-2560x1440-for-a-monitor-with-corrupt-edid), I had to find the EEID of my screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 340.76 version from edgers ppa works:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

Comment: Kindly include instructions on how to install the said 340.76 version using the ppa.